# Would a spoofed SMS message show up in the same chat history as a legitimate SMS?

Tags: spoofing, sms

I received an odd SMS message from xfinity earlier. The message looks real, and the link they provided is real, but they said I ordered a movie through their service, which I did not. I am wondering if spoofed SMS messages would show up in the same chat history, or if it would show up in a new chat history.

Comment: Welcome to the community. My guess would be that if the same caller ID got spoofed it would show up in the same chat history actually

Answer (score 0):

Yes. An SMS in both Android and iOS is attached to a thread with the same sender ID. As the sender ID is spoofed, the message will be included in the same thread.

Just a note: since spoofing a phone number is much harder than a name (since it is easier to prove you are the owner of the number), many countries have made it illegal to send SMS's using a name ID (you can find them [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133767-International-support-for-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID)).